# Помогите разобраться с методом array.indexOf()

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Не могу понять, как правильно сделать, чтобы метод `indexOf()` работал и выводил в консоль найденный элемент.

```
if (array.indexOf(element)) {
    console.log(element);
  } else {
    return -1 && console.log('Element not found');
}
```

Comment: `if (array.indexOf(element) >= 0) {`

Comment: `if (array.indexOf(element) > -1)` или `if (array.indexOf(element) != -1)`

Comment: `if (~array.indexOf(element))` Побитовое NOT до кучи :)

Comment: `-1` будет трактоваться как `true`. Используйте либо `indexOf(el) !== -1`, либо функцию [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.indexOf()` возвращает позицию найденного элемента в массиве (с нуля). Если элемент не был найден, то возвращается -1.

Сначала необходимо проверить, есть ли в массиве искомый элемент *вообще*, а уж потом его выводить. Для проверки на -1 (отсутствие элемента) можно воспользоваться битовыми операциями: код внутри блока if выполнится, если элемент в массиве найден. Кстати говоря, это справедливо только для тех случаев, если в массиве все индексы положительные (и да, это не обязательное условие, к сожалению).

```
if (~array.indexOf(element)) {
    // ...
}
```

В целом ответ может выглядеть так:

```
let index = array.indexOf(element); // получаем позицию элемента (-1, если не найден)

if (~index) { // равносильно array.indexOf(element) !== -1
    console.log(array[index]);
}
```

Пример выше выведет `element`, если он есть в массиве.

Первым делом мы записываем индекс найденного (или нет, пока не важно) элемента в переменную. Далее мы проверяем эту переменную. Если ее значение  - -1, то код не выполнится (если элемент не был найден). Если элемент был найден, то выводим элемент массива под индексом [index].

Стоит упомянуть, пожалуй, про читабельность такого кода. С одной стороны выглядит он намного красивее, а работает с таким же успехом (если не быстрее), но человек, читающий ваш код и незнакомый с подобного рода вещами может встать в ступор. Так что используйте на свое усмотрение.

Answer (score 2):

Если ты в массиве ищешь элемент советую использовать метод Array.find()
ссылка на доку: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Пример

```
const yourElement = element;
const findedElement = myArray.find(item => {
  return item === yourElement;
});
```

Array.find() вернет undefined если ничего не найдет

Answer (score -1):

```js
"use strict";

function findElementInArray(element, array) {

    if ( ~array.indexOf(element) ) {
        console.log(element);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Element not found');
}

findElementInArray(2, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); // 2
findElementInArray('a', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); // Element not found
```

Comment: Минусуещему - вы бы хоть удосужились углубиться в решение проблемы и признать правильность данного решения

Answer (score -2):

return -1; будет вызывать ошибку Illegal return statement, лучше вернуть строкой

```js
var index = array.indexOf(element);
if (index >=0) {
    console.log(array[index]);
  } else {
    console.log('Element not found with index ' + index)

}
```

Comment: `return -1; будет вызывать ошибку Illegal return statement,` **только** если он находится не в функции

Comment: ну это то я понимаю, но в вопросе нет функции-обёртки, я ведь даю ответ исходя из вопроса. Если у меня спросят как разрубить бревно шариковой ручкой, то я не буду описывать как его разрубить топором в ответе)